# Changing time format inside twisted matrix log

Tags: python, logging, twisted

how may i change the time format of the logging system used in TwistedMatrix ?

i have noticed from
http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-11.0.0/twisted/python/log.py#L389
that one should be allowed to change timeFormat, but it does not work
for me, here is my full test program that i execute `python myscript.py`

```
from twisted.internet import endpoints, reactor

from twisted.python import log
from twisted.application.service import Application
from twisted.python.log import ILogObserver, FileLogObserver
from twisted.python.logfile import DailyLogFile

#[... here my definition of a ProxyFactory()...]

application = Application("myapp")
logfile = DailyLogFile("my.log", './')
flo = FileLogObserver(logfile)
flo.timeFormat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f%z"
application.setComponent(ILogObserver, flo.emit)

log.startLogging(logfile)
log.msg("this is a test")

endpoint = endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, portstr)
d = endpoint.listen(ProxyFactory())
d.addErrback(shutdown, reactor)
reactor.run()
```

do not get the expected: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f%z" (milliseconds)

```
2013-06-12 17:08:07+0200 [-] Log opened.
2013-06-12 17:08:12+0200 [-] this is a test
```

what am i missing?

also:

- how must i proceed to change this time format, when i do not need file
  logging but only stderr printing?

( other reference: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/3513 )

EDIT: i tried to rephrase my two questions.

so from the answer posted by JeanPaul, i understand that i was mixing things and classic python file with another `tac` file (that i do not know before reading JeanPaul). BTW i tried this one below and do not still get the milliseconds i need:

(this time i am launching `twistd -noy my.tac`)

```
from twisted.application.service import Application
from twisted.python.log import ILogObserver, FileLogObserver
from twisted.python.logfile import DailyLogFile

application = Application("myapp")
logfile = DailyLogFile("my.log", "./")
flo = FileLogObserver(logfile)
flo.timeFormat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f %z"
application.setComponent(ILogObserver, flo.emit)
```

and get:

```
2013-06-13 17:23:23,%f+0000 [-] Log opened.
2013-06-13 17:23:23,%f+0000 [-] using set_wakeup_fd
2013-06-13 17:23:23,%f+0000 [-] twistd 12.0.0 (/usr/bin/python 2.7.3) starting up.
2013-06-13 17:23:23,%f+0000 [-] reactor class: twisted.internet.pollreactor.PollReactor.
2013-06-13 17:23:30,%f+0000 [-] Received SIGINT, shutting down.
2013-06-13 17:23:30,%f+0000 [-] Main loop terminated.
2013-06-13 17:23:30,%f+0000 [-] Server Shut Down.
```

as you can see if i mimic what is done @ http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/python/log.py#L351 , see line 367, python and time give me this milliseconds. notice also the %Z is wrong it should be +0200, but i will be able to live with that while i need milliseconds...

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 13:56:14)
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")
'17:28:06.566135'
>>> import time
>>> when = time.time()
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(when).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f%z")
'2013-06-13 17:33:20,535350'
>>> import twisted
>>> twisted.version
Version('twisted', 12, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing several different things to the logging system here.  You're asking `twistd` to use `flo.emit` as the log observer.  This will take effect once `twistd` has loaded the `application` defined in this *`tac` file*.  Then, you're manually initializing the logging system to use `logfile` and immediately logging a message.  Since this is part of the `tac` file, `twistd` has not yet finished loading the `application` so it has not yet applied the logging configuration you specified using `ILogObserver`.  Instead, the log event is handled by the log observer you set up with `startLogging` - `logfile`, which doesn't know anything about customized timestamp formatting.

Drop the `startLogging` call and you should see events that are logged *after* the `application` is loaded from the `tac` file get formatted properly.

You can read all about how logging works in Twisted in the [logging howto](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/logging.html) and how to configure it for `twistd` in the [application howto](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/application.html).

Also note that support for [custom time formatting using `datetime.strftime`](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/3513) was [first introduced in Twisted 13.0.0](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-13.0.0/NEWS?format=raw).  From the output in your question, it looks like you have Twisted 12.0.0.  This means the formatting is done using `time.strftime`, which does not support microseconds.

Prior to Twisted 13.0.0, to get microseconds in the time format, you need to override the `formatTime` method of `FileLogObserver` and call `datetime.strftime` yourself.

Comment: please what is the `tac` file? i actually really miss the right example.

Comment: The `tac` file is what you wrote.  It's a Python-syntax file that defines an `application` global name (and that does not call `reactor.run`).

Comment: ok so there is a misunderstanding as my program is what i have wrote first, but it contains also where i put [...] many others classes of my own an then ends with the reactor.run part in the same file. i have just remove the not necessary parts for my question about log.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking now.

Comment: please, one more question, is ti possible to change the behaviour and format when using the default `log.startlogging(sys.stdout)` paradigm?. many thanks

Comment: no, `startLogging` creates the `FileLogObserver` for you; you have no chance to customize its `timeFormat`.

Answer (score 1):

if this could help someone here it is (file called my.tac)

i also have made %z to work correctly (i now get +0200 as expected when using my own timeformat instead of +0000)

i call this with `twistd -noy my.tac`

( inspired by http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/python/log.py#L407 )

```
from twisted.application.service import Application
from twisted.python.log import ILogObserver, FileLogObserver
from twisted.python.logfile import DailyLogFile

from datetime import datetime

class MyFileLogObserver(FileLogObserver):

    def formatTime(self, when):
        """
        Format the given UTC value as a string representing that time in the
        local timezone.

        By default it's formatted as a ISO8601-like string (ISO8601 date and
        ISO8601 time separated by a space). It can be customized using the
        C{timeFormat} attribute, which will be used as input for the underlying
        L{datetime.datetime.strftime} call.

        BACKPORTED VERSION: and adding support for %z.

        @type when: C{int}
        @param when: POSIX (ie, UTC) timestamp for which to find the offset.

        @rtype: C{str}
        """
        tzOffset = -self.getTimezoneOffset(when)
        tzHour = abs(int(tzOffset / 60 / 60))
        tzMin = abs(int(tzOffset / 60 % 60))
        if tzOffset < 0:
            tzSign = '-'
        else:
            tzSign = '+'
        tz = "%s%02d%02d" % (tzSign, tzHour, tzMin)
        if self.timeFormat is not None:
            return datetime.fromtimestamp(when).strftime(self.timeFormat.replace("%z", tz))

        when = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(when + tzOffset)    
        return '%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d%s%02d%02d' % (
                when.year, when.month, when.day,
                when.hour, when.minute, when.second,
                tzSign, tzHour, tzMin)    

application = Application("myapp")
logfile = DailyLogFile("my.log", "./")
flo = MyFileLogObserver(logfile)
flo.timeFormat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f%z"
application.setComponent(ILogObserver, flo.emit)
```

Comment: great, what changes if I'd like to push logs on `stdout` or whatever it's called in Python?